# read a variable in another program using c

Tags: c, pointers

I want to use a program to read a variable with a given address in another program using c. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
volatile unsigned int *a;
int main(){
    scanf("%d",&a);//input the pointer to the variable I want to read
    while(1){
        printf("%d\n",*a);
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

To test this program, I used another program to change the variable. This is the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
volatile unsigned int a;
int main(){
    printf("%d\n",&a);//output the pointer to the variable
    while(1)scanf("%d",&a);
}
```

I run the second program first and then type the output of the variable into the first program. It's wired that every time I run the second program, I get the same output. And when I run the first program, I get the same value every time, despite I changed the variable in the second program. Why doesn't it work? My computer is 32-bit.

Comment: each program has it's own virtual memory. That is the same address in program A and B is mapped to a different physical memory adress

Comment: And all your calls to `printf` `scanf` are broken.

Comment: It will never do what you want. And for that please read the manuals for those functions.

Comment: @iharob what do you mean by that?

Comment: On which operating system?

Answer (score 6):

It is [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific, and you generally should avoid doing that -even when possible-. Prefer other [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) facilities (e.g. pipes, sockets, [message passing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing))

On most OSes, each [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) has its *own* [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) in [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), so a process A cannot change any data in process B. BTW, two processes can run simultaneously (on different cores) or quasi-simultaneously (with their tasks scheduled by the kernel), so sharing without care a variable does not make any sense.

Some OSes provide [shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) facilities, but then you should care about [synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization) (e.g. with [semaphores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29)).

For Linux, read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) & [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html)

Generally, you need to design and adapt both programs to make them communicate. For [security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_security) reasons you don't want (and your OS [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28operating_system%29) forbids) arbitrary processes to be able to glance in other processes' address space.

<sup>For example, you don't want your game software to be able to access your banking data in your browser without your consent.</sup>

Alternatively, merge the two programs into a single [multi-threaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29#Multithreading) application. You'll be concerned by synchronization and probably would need to use [mutexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion). Read e.g. some [POSIX threads tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

See also [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface). BTW, you might use some [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) to share the common data (look into [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/), [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org/), etc...) or adapt a [client-server model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model)

Comment: So what should I do if I want to read a variable in another program?

Comment: You cannot do that in general. You need to adapt both programs to agree on some IPC.